# Include static files in sitemap.xml in gatsby

Tags: gatsby

We have pdf files that we want to include in sitemap.xml. How to accomplish that using `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`? We can list pdf files using graphql but it's unobvious to covert the results to page objects.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
  options: {
    query: `
    {
      allFile(filter: {extension: {eq: "pdf"}}) {
        nodes {
          publicURL
        }
      }
    }
    `,
    resolvePages({}) => {
      // Don't know what should we return here.
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to include as well as the PDF and the rest of the pages, so you'll need to create two different queries. Something like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
  options: {
    query: `
    {
      pdfs: allFile(filter: {extension: {eq: "pdf"}}) {
        nodes {
          publicURL
        }
      }
      pages: allSitePage {
         nodes {
           path
         }
          }
    }
    `,
    resolvePages({pages, pdfs}) => {
         const pdfsNodeMap = pdfs.reduce((acc, node) => {
            const { uri } = node
            acc[uri] = node

            return acc
          }, {})

          return pages.map(page => {
            return { ...page, ...pdfsNodeMap[page.path] }
          })
    },
  }
}
```

*Note: check the enclosing brackets because it's difficult to write code in a markdown editor*

`resolvePages` will return your nodes (destrucuted as `pdfs` and `pages` because of the alias). I don't know what is returning your PDF query, but I assumed an `uri` that needs to be concatenated and mixed with the rest of the pages. Of course, this is an approximation not a final but get the idea. Tweak it as you wish.